# Java regex split string not working

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string with regex in Java.

I need to get an array : `A`, `B`, `01/01/2016 12:31`, `D`

why my regex doesn't work ? it will output the original string.

```
String source = "A|B|[01/01/2016 12:31]|D";     
String regex = "\\|\\|\\[.*\\]\\|";

String[] array = source.split(regex);
for(String data: array){
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: The regex does not match the input string as it expects two consecutive pipes (at the start of the pattern).

Comment: great, if I change it to this, still not work : \\|.*\\|\\[.*\\]\\|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex does not match the input string as it expects two consecutive pipes (at the start of the pattern). To be more precise, `\|\|\[.*\]\|` matches 2 pipes followed by a `[` followed with zero or more characters other than a newline (as many as possible) followed with `]` and a `|`.

You need to use the following regex:

```
String regex = "[|\\[\\]]+";
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/oUib3g)

This regex will match one or more characters: `|`, `]` or `[`.

Comment: We need a `+` because otherwise, we'll get empty elements in the array. Also, it is worth noting that you need to escape `[` and `]` inside the character class in a Java regex.

Comment: sorry, don't understand, can you give me a web link ?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the 2nd line to something as below for the input string format and calling split with -1 should handle all situations when the tokens are empty including the last one

```
String regex = "((\\|\\[)|(\\]\\|)|(\\|))";

String[] array = source.split(regex, -1);
```

the above gives following output for 'A|B|[01/01/2016 12:31]|D' in case of empty D as well it prints a zero string.

```
A
B
01/01/2016 12:31
D
```

This though will work for input strings of the format A|B|[C]|D, the other regex mentioned on the thread [[|\[\]]]+ will handle square brackets showing anywhere in the input along with | separator as long as there are no zero strings, for example A||[C]|D will result in shifting of tokens.

Comment: But you forget about the square brackets.

Comment: That's right missed the square brackets what you have down below will work to remove square brackets as well!

Comment: Thanks, you make a good point, if the end is empty, like A||[C]|D| , your regex didn't cover it. how to do it ?

Comment: You can do the following  with the same regex in place call split with regex and a negative value source.split(regex, -1), this will ensure from one of the separator to end of string will be captured as well in case of zero string as last token