# Split String at "?"

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to play around with strings and the regex expressions. Regex has a few spezial characters like "(", "[", "*", "^", and "?". Just to name a few examples. I already know, if I want to split a string at a bracket, that I have to use
`String string = "foo(bar";
string.split("\(");` to split at the bracket. Just with the "?" it does not work. How could I split a string at the quotation mark like: `"foo?bar" -> "foo" + "bar"`
Cheers

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489987/java-regex-split-string-not-working (TL;DR escape the backslash also: `"foo?bar".split("\\?")`)

Comment: `string.split("\(");` will throw an "illegal escape character" error. You will need to escape the bracket the same way as you escape the question mark.

Comment: I would stop trying to do the language stringing and the regex stringing (metachars) at the same time. Always do the raw regex string first. This is what is seen by the regex engine. If you want the engine to interpret and match a metacharacter as a literal, escape it for the engine. I.e.  `\(` or `\)` or `\[` or `\]` or `\+` or `\*` or `\?`, etc... Then, put it into a Java string layer, escaping the escapes `"\\("` or `"\\)"` or `"\\["` or `"\\]"` or `"\\+"` or `"\\*"` or `"\\?"`, etc... As an exercise, you must type this out by hand once so you never forget.